Nested div elemment onclick calls all div's click event
I have html code as bellow;
<div onclick=alert("First div")>
    <div onclick=alert("Second div")>
        <div onclick=alert("Third div")>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

The problem is when inner most div is clicked all three alert message displayed.
How can I modify the code so that only 1 alert message will display corresponding to div tag.

good thing to read up on the event bubble and event delegation.

It's a bit of a code smell to add click handlers to presentation elements like divs. If you could tell us a little more about what you're trying to achieve we can perhaps suggest some alternatives.

You can achieve this by stopping the event propagation when the innermost div is clicked. This way, the click event won't bubble up to the parent divs.
<script>
    function handleClick(event) {
        if (event.target.tagName === 'DIV') {
            switch (event.target.className) {
                case 'first':
                    alert('First div');
                    break;
                case 'second':
                    alert('Second div');
                    break;
                case 'third':
                    alert('Third div');
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<div class="first" onclick="handleClick(event)">
   First Div
    <div class="second" onclick="handleClick(event); event.stopPropagation();">
        Second Div
        <div class="third" onclick="handleClick(event); event.stopPropagation();">
             Third Div
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>


While it solves the issue, the code got worse. Go either for a full event delegation or at least move the script to a dedicated function to not make it repetitive.

Thanks for you help but sorry to say sir not working same problem exist with provided code.

I have edited the code.Could you try this approach?
